# Accessing YUV data in openCV on the RPi

Tags: python, opencv, raspivid

I came across [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32926/convert-the-frame-data-from-recording-into-a-numpy-array)question and answer which said how to get a numpy array from raspicam, using the PiYUVAnalysis class.

I can output the array itself, But i do not know how to view the array as an image using openCV?
I would like to view the images frame by frame in real time using openCV.

If anyone could help me out with this, I would highly appreciate it!

I essentially tried append this :

```
img = cv2.imread('ArrayY',0)
```

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

To the end of the code, but it did not work :/ 
Thank you in advance for your help!
Cheers,
David

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681756/how-to-convert-a-python-numpy-array-to-an-rgb-image-with-opencv-2-4) could be your answer. They do not simply pass the array, but either write it to file and read, or split to channels and pass them as arguments.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.Unfortunately, I am kind of a beginner and I do not really know exactly what is going on in the linked code. IS there any way you could explain it to me?